# Nginx on VM on ded. root server has very slow download rates

Tags: nginx, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, http, dedicated-server

I'm running VMware ESXI on a kimsufi dedicated root with 100Mbit/s network access.

As the root has only 1 public IPv4 available and ESXi cannot NAT its VMs, I assigned the public IP to VM#1 which is running pfsense. All other VMs are NATed through this virtual router.

I run nginx on Ubuntu Server on VM#2 and I created a protected directory from which I want to download large files (>4GB) directly. I used pretty much the default nginx configuration, will post it however if it helps.

The download speeds i get from this server are very slow (256kb/s) and much below what my home or server internet connection is capable of.

How can I efficiently test where the bottleneck is (and what options are available in nginx to increase download rates)?

Answer (score 0):

To have an idea of what you can reasonably expect at the top end, I would try a straight file copy (scp or whatever) from your source to destination.  That will rule out any nginx configuration.  If you still get 256kbps, then you can check into potential kernel variables, or the possibility that the network is throttled administratively.

---

Nginx is not going to be a fast way to do file transfer, especially if you have one of the cheaper dedicated servers.  You are adding layers of latency/inefficiency above and beyond a straight file copy.  For troubleshooting, you can also try streaming multiple files at the same time to see if you get 256kbps each, or if that number is your overall cap.

---

The nginx config proxy_max_temp_file_size may be set very small.  You can increase this to a number above the size of the files you are serving, which may help